# Better way to build relational database with EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I am new to EF Core and having troubles with designing proper models.

My goal is to have three database tables:

1. **Users** (contains users of an application(using Identity));
2. **Lanuages** (indicates what languages a user can speak) with following columns:

   - Id
   - UserId
   - LanguageId
3. **LanguagesList** (static list of available languages) with following columns:

   - Id
   - Name
   - Code
   - *etc*.

The idea is to bind users and their languages via third table which would include only ids like this:

```
Id    UserId    LanguageId
1     56        1
2     56        2
3     57        1
```

The classes I create are:

**User class:**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public List<Language> SpokenLanguages { get; set; }
}
```

**Lanuages:**

```
public class Language
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public LanguageList LanguageList { get; set; }
}
```

And **LanguageList**

```
public class LanguageList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

My **database context class**:

```
public class ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LanguageList> LanguageList { get; set; }
}
```

The way I am trying to update database is (console style):

```
public class _TestController : Controller
{
    // Database context.
    private ApplicationContext ApplicationContext { get; set; }
    // ctor
    public _TestController(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        this.ApplicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<LanguageList> allLanguages = this.ApplicationContext.LanguageList.ToList();
        ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();

        Language language = new Language
        {
            LanguageList = allLanguages.FirstOrDefault(lang => lang.Name == "English"),
            User = user
        };

        user.SpokenLanguages = new List<Language>();
        user.SpokenLanguages.Add(language);

        this.ApplicationContext.Languages.Add(language);
        this.ApplicationContext.Users.Add(user);
        this.ApplicationContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This code creates proper rows in data tables, but when I am trying to get an ApplicationUser from context it's property SpokenLanguages is always null.

What is wrong with this code and why value of SpokenLanguages property is always null?

Comment: You should also show the code that pulls users from the database. Also, a more common convention would be to use tables names `User`, `Language` (instead of your LanguageList) and the connection between them: `UserLanguage`.

Comment: Are you doing an `Include()` ? var user = context.Users.Include(u => u.SpokenLanguages).Single(u => u.UserName == userName);

Comment: Appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some relations set up, but EF won’t follow those relations unless you tell it to. You do this with the `Include` method:

```
var users = ApplicationContext.Users.Include(u => u.SpokenLanguages).ToList();
```

... or something like that.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the link.